# Conversion Issue on Python's int()

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-2.x

When I run this code:

```
value = 11.20
dollars = int(value)
print dollars
print 100 * (value - dollars)
```

Unsurprisingly, I got `11` and `20.0`, respectively.

However, when added this line:

```
print int(100 * (value - dollars))
```

I got `19`.

I searched the web, and got an explanation:

> But 0.20 is different. Inside the computer, it's actually a slightly smaller number, so multiplying by 100 gives 19.99999.... When int cuts off the part after the decimal point, 19 is left as the result, instead of the expected 20.

Then I tried:

```
value_tmp = 0.20
print int(value_tmp * 100)
```

I got `20`, not `19`, what's the problem here?

Comment: try converting it to float.

Comment: This is the issue with floats - you may not get exactly the same result from calculations you would expect to be equal (i.e. calculating the same number in two different ways may give two *slightly* different results). For that reason, you generally test float equality with a tolerance (i.e. `abs(a - b) < tolerance` rather than `a == b`).

Comment: You clould round your number

Comment: Never use floats for money. Use an integer to store the number of cents, a tuple to store integer dollars and integer cents separately, or a rational type that can stores hundredths of a unit precisely.

Comment: 11.20-11 is 0.1999999999999993 not 0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *close approximation* of 20.0:

```
>>> value = 11.20
>>> dollars = int(value)
>>> 100 * (value - dollars)
19.99999999999993
```

That's because you cannot accurately model 2/10th with floating point numbers:

```
>>> value
11.2
>>> format(value, '.53f')
'11.19999999999999928945726423989981412887573242187500000'
```

By multiplying the decimal part by 100 you amplified that imprecision. To add to that `int()` on a `float` number *floors* the result.

You could instead round the number to the nearest integer:

```
>>> round(100 * (value - dollars), 0)
20.0
>>> int(round(100 * (value - dollars), 0))
20
```